# What is the best way to test hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, testing, apache-zookeeper, namenode

I have completed the hadoop cluster setup with 3 journal nodes for QJM, 4 datanodes, 2 namenode, 3 zookeeper but I need to confirm whether the connectivity had made successfully between them so, I am searching for a too which can perform the following task

1) Should check which namenode currently in active state

2) Is both the namenode is communicating with each other successfully

3) Should check whether all journal nodes are communicating with each other successfully

4) Should check whether all zookeeper are communicating with each other successfully

5) Which zookeeper currently playing the master role

Is there any tool or any commands available to check above task?

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: You might want to just install Apache Ambari to monitor the entire cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ambari you can monitor complete cluster performace and working.
Also if you want to validate your hadoop jobs programatically,
Then you can use the concept of Counters in Hadoop.